Mismatched versions warning when updating Node.js/NPM in Docker
In our Dockerfile we have:
FROM ghcr.io/puppeteer/puppeteer:latest AS pdf
WORKDIR /puppeteer
USER root

# Prerequisites
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install nginx -y

# Update
RUN npm update
RUN npm update -g
RUN npm install -g npm

# Dependencies
RUN npm install puppeteer

# Run
COPY ./pdf.js .
RUN chmod u+x pdf.js
RUN service nginx start && ./pdf.js

This waits for Nginx to start and then runs a Node.js script (which crawls some pages on the Nginx webserver).
Are the commands correct in # Update? Does the order of the commands matter, in order for it to update properly and fully?
Node.js/NPM appears to update but throws the following warning in the console whilst it works (it takes some time):
#43 3.167 npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
#43 3.169 npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'corepack@0.28.0',
#43 3.170 npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^18.17.1 || >=20.10.0' },
#43 3.172 npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v20.9.0', npm: '10.1.0' }
#43 3.174 npm WARN EBADENGINE }

How can we fix this warning about an unsupported engine/mismatched versions? I.E. how can we update from Node v20.9.0 to v20.10.0 (or latest)?
Docker specifically recommend that you should use apt-get update in their best practices. Should we also be updating Node.js/NPM like the above? Could updating potentially cause any issues for our install of Google Puppeteer? I.E. because those later versions are untested on puppeteer:latest by Google.

Since you’re basing your image on the Puppeteer image, you should be able to use the Puppeteer installation that’s already provided in that image. This would ensure that the Node.js setup is consistent with what the Puppeteer developers expect.
Puppeteer is installed in /home/pptruser and is intended for use by the pptruser user. You’ll have to change your entrypoint to be a script which starts nginx (as root) and then changes to pptruser to run your script.

Hi Stephen, thanks for your answer! When you say we "should be able to use the Puppeteer installation that's already provided", you're also referring to Node.js & NPM right? So the advice is don't update them. Thanks for the extra piece of advice for pptruser too!

I’m referring to everything that’s already in the base image: Node.js, NPM, and the Puppeteer module and its dependencies. The provided base image is consistent, so yes, don’t update anything — the image is updated frequently anyway.
